# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I create a component like so:

```
let bList = bObj.map((obj, index) => {
        let { 
            icon, htmlType, onClick } = obj;

        let _b = <Button 
                    htmlType = { htmlType } 
                    icon = { icon }
                    onClick = { () => {this._onClick()} } />

        if(someVar) {
            return (
                <AnotherComp style = { someVar } 
                    key = { index } >
                    { _b }
                </AnotherComp>
            );

        } else {
            return (
                { _b }
            );
        }
    });

bList = 
    <div style = { wrap }>
        <myComp style = { grp }> 
            { buttonsList } 
        </myComp>
    </div>

return bList;
```

That returns me

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_bu}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `MyComp`.

However, when I write it like this:

```
let bList = bObj.map((obj, index) => {
        let { 
            icon, htmlType, onClick } = obj;

        if(someVar) {
            return (
                <AnotherComp style = { someVar } 
                    key = { index } >
                    <Button 
                        htmlType = { htmlType } 
                        icon = { icon }
                        onClick = { () => {this._onClick()} } />
                </AnotherComp>
            );

        } else {
            return (
                <Button 
                    htmlType = { htmlType } 
                    icon = { icon }
                    onClick = { () => {this._onClick()} } />
            );
        }
    });

bList = 
    <div style = { wrap }>
        <MyComp style = { grp }> 
            { buttonsList } 
        </MyComp>
    </div>

return bList;
```

It works. Where is the difference between saving `<Button ../>` in a variable and writing it in there directly?!

Comment: What is `buttonsList`? Is the first line in each example supposed to be the declaration for `buttonsList` instead of `bList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is you are using extra `{}`, remove that it will work:

```
return  _b;
```

Meaning of `return ({ _b })` is:

```
return ({'_b' : _b});
```

That means you are returning an `object` with key `_b`, not the `JSX`.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = 5;

let b = { a };

console.log('b = ', b);
```

Comment: oh my gosh. Thanks a lot!